# Django mptt throwing error when order insertion value is changed

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I have this mptt model:

```
class Program_requirement_category(MPTTModel):
    display_order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    min_credit = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    max_credit = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['display_order']
```

When i try to insert some value into the db, i get the following error:

```
File "/home/abhishek/projects/mptttree/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1074, in build_filter
    raise ValueError("Cannot use None as a query value")
ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value
```

I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596115/how-to-order-django-mptt-tree-by-datetimefield) and wanted a similar work around for my problem as well. How do i get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From mptt documentation:

> **order_insertion_by** A list of field names which should define ordering when new tree nodes are being inserted or existing nodes are
>   being reparented, with the most significant ordering field name first.
>   Defaults to [].
>   **It is assumed that any field identified as defining ordering will
>   never be NULL in the database.**